Dax formula to see latest week sales for a selected itinerary and its 4 week average
I have a column called as at date that gives a snapshot of sales by countries. I would like to filter out the latest week as a measure "This Week". At the same time I want to see what is the 4 week average across the last 4 as at week to benchmark.
I believe I have to use Max(As At Date) to filter out the latest week revenue.
I tried calculating the 4 week average using :
Last 4 weeks Average = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Held Sales '[Held NPR TY]), FILTER(ALL('Held Sales'[AsAt Week]),'Held Sales '[AsAt Week]<=max('Held Sales '[AsAt Week])-4 ))

This is a sample of how the data set looks like: 

could you pls provide more sample data and the expected output based on the sample data?
